# I have a downladed file from ssh but it takes 50 seconds to complete the download

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ssh

I am using vb.net to download a file and using Tamir.SharpSsh which works well except its slow it takes about 50 seconds to download a 3.5 kb file. My Question is How would I best put a wait function in for 2 mins to ensure the file is downloaded.

```
Public Function DownloadPricat() As Boolean
    Dim retVal As Boolean
    Dim PRICAT_CSV As String
    Dim sfilename As String = ""
    Dim ifilename As String

    utils = New ThreeSoftware.Configuration.Utilities.utilConfigurationLoader("CONFIGURATION FILES\GEMINI RELATED\SkechersImport.ini")

    Hostname = utils.GetIniSetting("SSH SECTION", "SSH_HOST", "")
    username = utils.GetIniSetting("SSH SECTION", "SSH_USERNAME", "")
    passsword = utils.GetIniSetting("SSH SECTION", "SSH_PASSWORD", "")
    port = utils.GetIniSetting("SSH SECTION", "SSH_PORT", "")
    HomeDirectoy = utils.GetIniSetting("SSH SECTION", "SSH_REMOTE_DIRECTORY", "")


    transfer = New wcSFtp(Hostname, Integer.Parse(port), username, passsword)

    PRICAT_CSV = utils.GetIniSetting("PATHS SECTION", "PRICAT_CSV", "")
    sfilename = utils.GetIniSetting("PATHS SECTION", "PRICAT_FILENAME", "")

    ifilename = PRICAT_CSV & "\" & sfilename
    If transfer.getFile(HomeDirectoy & "Pricat.edi", ifilename) = True Then
        MsgBox("Download Complete", vbInformation, "Import")
        retVal = True
    Else

        retVal = False
    End If

End Function
```

Get File is simply this

```
Public Function getFile(ByVal remotePath As String, ByVal localFile As String) As Boolean
    Try
        transfer = New Sftp(Me._hostname, Me._username, Me._password)
        transfer.Connect(Me._port)
        transfer.Get(remotePath, localFile)
        transfer.Close()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print("Error downloading file: " & ex.ToString)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: I strongly advise against a time delay to make sure something is finished. This creates a racing condition that may or may not work and in the best of cases creates unwanted additional wait time for the user. In the worst case the task is still not finished after your fixed delay and something breaks.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong with the library used if 3.5Kb download takes a minute. Use more adequate SFTP client components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the whole download into a backgroundworker's `DoWork()` function and add the Boolean result as the result-variable of the eventargs variable.
Then handle the RunWorkerCompleted() event of the backgroundworker and perform whatever task you want to happen after the download from there. That way you make sure the download is actually finished.

```
Public Class Form1
Private WithEvents LazyBGW As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Initiate the backgroundworker. It runs in another thread.
    LazyBGW.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub LazyBGW_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles LazyBGW.DoWork
    'This code runs in the BGW-Thread
    'Perform the whole download task here or just call your 
    e.Result = DownloadPricat()
    'Work is done, put results in the eventargs-variable for further processing
End Sub

Private Sub LazyBGW_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles LazyBGW.RunWorkerCompleted
    'This code runs in the UI-Thread
    Dim results As Boolean = CBool(e.Result)
    MessageBox.Show("The worker is done and our result is: " & results.ToString)
End Sub
End Class
```

Edit:
In a console app you can use a Task:

```
Module Module1
Private Function DownloadPricat() As Boolean
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
    Return True
End Function
Sub Main()
    Dim DLTask As New System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Boolean)(Function() DownloadPricat())
    DLTask.Start()
    Dim ThisTime As Date = Date.Now
    Console.Write("Downloading")
    While DLTask.IsCompleted = False AndAlso DLTask.IsCanceled = False AndAlso DLTask.IsFaulted = False
        If (Date.Now - ThisTime).TotalSeconds > 1 Then
            Console.Write(".")
            ThisTime = Date.Now
        End If
    End While
    Console.Write("Done.")
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: that works ok for  a gui app I also need be able to do this via automation as well?

Comment: In a console app? Do you need other stuff happening while the file downloads?

Comment: I added an example for a console app.

Comment: it not a console app just auotmation class for a winforms app

Comment: I can't help you there I guess.